# Java - Generics with statics

Tags: java, generics, static

stuck on something that should be pretty simple.

I have the class TreeSort:

```
public class TreeSort {

    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void sort(E[] nums) {
        //Sorting
    }
}
```

And a simple Tester class with a main method for testing:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TreeStructureException {

        int[] nums = { 11, 2, 8, 30, 12, 21, 6, 4, 3, 18 };
        TreeSort.sort(nums); // The method sort(E[]) in the type TreeSort is not 
                             // applicable for the arguments (int[])
    }
```

}

Why do I get this error? Thanks all

Comment: Because an `int[]` isn't an `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int[] nums` is an `Object`. You have two ways to solve this:

- Change the variable to `Integer[]`.
- Create an additional method to support `int[]`.

In case you're not doing this for homework/exercise/specific sort algorithm purpose, use [`Arrays#sort(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int%3aA-) or [`Arrays#sort(Object[] array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object%3aA-) instead.

Comment: Thanks, that was the ticket. Needed to use Integer[]

Answer (score 2):

Primitives and generics aren't really compatible.  You'll either need a Integer[] (gross) or sort should take a int[].

Comment: What's gross about Integer[]?

Comment: @NWard The memory overhead from boxing, loss of memory locality when traversing the array, and an extra pointer dereference for each element accessed mainly.

Comment: You're correct, needed to change int[] to Integer[]